# Org table: aggregate each column (but not the header column)

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I would like to [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) this table example from [Org as a spreadsheet system: a short introduction](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-spreadsheet-intro.html):

```
| Student  | Maths | Physics | Mean |
|----------+-------+---------+------|
| Bertrand |    13 |      09 |   11 |
| Henri    |    15 |      14 | 14.5 |
| Arnold   |    17 |      13 |   15 |
#+TBLFM: $4=vmean($2..$3)
```

This part is easy:

```
| Student | Bertrand | Henri | Arnold |
| Maths   |       13 |    15 |     17 |
| Physics |       09 |    14 |     13 |
| Total   |          |       |        |
#+TBLFM: @4=vmean(@2..@3)
```

But after a full recalculation (`C-u C-c C-c`), the text `(Maths + Physics) / 2` is inserted:

```
| Student               | Bertrand | Henri | Arnold |
| Maths                 |       13 |    15 |     17 |
| Physics               |       09 |    14 |     13 |
| (Maths + Physics) / 2 |       11 |  14.5 |     15 |
#+TBLFM: @4=vmean(@2..@3)
```

How do I treat the first column as a header column? I think this would solve the problem.

Update 2014-01-07 6:26 PM EST: The two answers (by [Juanco](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7146) and [wvxvw](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7145)) work, but is there a way to solve this without changing the formula line at all? Is there a way to tell Org mode that the leftmost column is a header column?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify the target cells for the formula to avoid overwriting the first column.

One way is the following:

```
#+TBLFM: @4$<<..@4$>=vmean(@2..@3)
```

Where `$<<` refers to the second column, and `$>` to the last.

Answer (score 3):

You also need to specify the range on the left hand side:

```
| Student | Bertrand | Henri | Arnold |
|---------+----------+-------+--------|
| Maths   |       13 |    15 |     17 |
| Physics |       09 |    14 |     13 |
|---------+----------+-------+--------|
| Total   |       11 |  14.5 |     15 |
#+TBLFM: @4$2..@$4=vmean(@2..@3)
```

If I understood you correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your questions & concerns correctly, you want to:

1. Transpose an org-mode table
2. Use the `#+TBLFM: @4=vmean(@2..@3)` formula but this
   overwrites the word **Total** with **(Maths + Physics) / 2** which is unacceptable.
3. Leave the `#+TBLFM: @4=vmean(@2..@3)` line **as-is** but have org-mode ignore first column in the table when applying the formula.

There is feature that will instructs org-mode to ignore the first column, `:rownames`, or first row, `:colnames`, of a table when performing calculations.
Unfortunately, you will need to pass the table into code block.

Simple example demonstrating `:rownames` and `:colnames` headers on a code block.

```
#+NAME: ex-rownames-colnames
|   | C |  D |
|---+---+----|
| A | 2 |  9 |
| B | 4 | 16 |

#+name: add-ten-to-table
#+header: :colnames yes 
#+header: :rownames yes
#+header: :var tab=ex-rownames-colnames
#+Begin_src python
   return [[val + 10 for val in row] for row in tab]
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: add-ten-to-table
|   |  C |  D |
|---+----+----|
| A | 12 | 19 |
| B | 14 | 26 |
```

Using this method to solve your **total** display issue is probably *overkill*.

The simplest solution is to modify `#+TBLFM: @4=vmean(@2..@3)` as [Juanco](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7146/388) or [wvxvw](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7145/388) suggested.

Hope that helped.